# how to limit charcter length in textfield in iphone

Tags: xcode

I want to limit the characters entering into a text field.For example only 10 numbers should be entered.After entering 10th number the textfield should resignfirstresponder.

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use a UITextField function:

```
-(BOOL) textField: (UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange) range replacementString:(NSString*) string 
{
NSInteger len = [textField.text length];
if ( len > maxChars )
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

where maxChars have value a 9

UPD: Thanks to [H2CO3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529758/h2co3)

Comment: -(BOOL) textField: (UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange) range replacementString:(NSString*) string 
{
NSInteger len = [textField.text length];
if ( len > maxChars )
   return [textfield resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}                                                                    Will this work for resignfirstreponder?